# Does > really need to be converted into an HTML entity?

Tags: html, escaping

I am wondering if the symbol `>` *always* needs to be converted into `&gt;`, if the input is coming from a user? I could understand that `<` (`&lt;`) would need to, since the next characters could be interpreted as HTML, but what harm could `>` have?

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you are going to do with the data.  If you're going to render it to a page, it should be HTML-escaped (meaning converted to >).  If you're doing pretty much anything else then it should not.